# Issue declaring let in a function

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to clear a setTimer() every time a key is pressed in my text input box, as my text input keeps sending update requests mid-typing, causing problems. However the code I have to tackle this issue is not working, due to the placement of my 'let', however I've put it everywhere I can think of, or changed to 'Var' and still not functioning. I'd appreciate on input on how I can retool this to achieve my desired result.

JS:

```
      computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allDocumentTypeGroups', 'currentTicketCaseFiles', 'activeAttachmentIndex', 'showAttachmentsPreview', 'activeAttachments']),

    attachmentAcceptedLabel() {
      return this.attachmentAccepted ? this.t('accepted') : this.t('ignored');
    },
    attachmentAccepted: {
      get: function () {
        return !this.attachment.ignoreAttachment;
      },
      set: function (val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { ignoreAttachment: !val }]);
      },
    },
    documentType: {
      get: function() {
        return this.attachment.documentTypeId;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { documentTypeId: val }]);
      },
    },
    approveAttachment: {
      get: function() {
        return this.attachment.approvedAttachment;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { approvedAttachment: val }]);
      },
    },
    strValue: {
      let timer;
      get: function () {
        return this.attachment.strValue;
      },
      set: function (val) {
        if(timer){
          clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        let self = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function(){ return self.updateAttachment([self.attachment.id, { strValue: val }]) },8000);
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: `let timer;` isn’t in a function. It’s in an object literal. Lexical declarations cannot be put directly in an object literal.

Comment: Make it a property: `timer: null`. Then use `self.timer`

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for your explanation, then where in this case would you suggest it be placed? As I've moved it around and not had any success.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put variables in an object literal, use a property.

```
    strValue: {
      timer: null,
      get: function () {
        return this.attachment.strValue;
      },
      set: function (val) {
        if(this.timer){
          clearTimeout(this.timer);
        }
        let self = this;
        this.timer = setTimeout(function(){ return self.updateAttachment([self.attachment.id, { strValue: val }]) },8000);
      },
    },
```